# Zygote be in loop in Android emulator that run with custm kernel

Tags: android, android-emulator, kernel, emulation, android-kernel

I currently want to run my compiled android kernel with emulator but emulator doesn't work correctly and just show black page on phone screen.
I use these commands for downloading and compiling android kernel:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/goldfish/ -b android goldfish-3.18
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/x86/x86_64-linux-android-4.9
cd goldfish
export CROSS_COMPILE=x86_64-linux-android-
export ARCH=x86_64
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/x86_64-linux-android-4.9/bin
make x86_64_ranchu_defconfig
make menuconfig  # enable overlayfs and namespaces support here
make -j8
```

after that i use emulator of SDK to run my kernel with these command:
(I use Android 7.0 x86_64 google api level 24 for Nexus_5X_API_23)

```
./emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_24 -kernel ~/Desktop/goldfish/arch/x86/boot/bzImage -show-kernel
```

but after that these text is coming on terminal (come and again come) and screen of mobile is showing boot animation.

```
[  270.896420] init: Service 'audioserver' is being killed...
[  270.897184] init: Service 'cameraserver' is being killed...
[  270.897986] init: Service 'media' is being killed...
[  270.898725] init: Service 'netd' is being killed...
[  270.899573] init: Service 'audioserver' (pid 6354) killed by signal 9
[  270.900441] init: Service 'audioserver' (pid 6354) killing any children in process group
[  270.901661] init: Service 'cameraserver' (pid 6355) killed by signal 9
[  270.902456] init: Service 'cameraserver' (pid 6355) killing any children in process group
[  270.903456] init: Service 'media' (pid 6356) killed by signal 9
[  270.904071] init: Service 'media' (pid 6356) killing any children in process group
[  270.904909] init: Service 'netd' (pid 6357) killed by signal 9
[  270.905518] init: Service 'netd' (pid 6357) killing any children in process group
[  270.915485] init: Service 'zygote_secondary' (pid 6587) killed by signal 11
[  270.916367] init: Service 'zygote_secondary' (pid 6587) killing any children in process group
[  271.918795] init: Starting service 'audioserver'...
[  271.919822] init: Starting service 'cameraserver'...
[  271.920826] type=1400 audit(1501255007.918:530): avc: denied { getattr } for pid=6598 comm="audioserver" path="/vendor" dev="rootfs" ino=6328 scontext=u:r:audioserver:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:rootfs:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0
[  271.920848] init: couldn't write 6599 to /dev/cpuset/camera-daemon/tasks: No such file or directory
[  271.920871] init: Starting service 'media'...
[  271.921227] init: Starting service 'netd'...
[  271.927633] type=1400 audit(1501255007.918:531): avc: denied { getattr } for pid=6599 comm="cameraserver" path="/vendor" dev="rootfs" ino=6328 scontext=u:r:cameraserver:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:rootfs:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0
[  272.523185] type=1400 audit(1501255008.518:532): avc: denied { module_request } for pid=6601 comm="netd" kmod="netdev-dummy0" scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=0
[  272.524725] type=1400 audit(1501255008.518:533): avc: denied { module_request } for pid=6601 comm="netd" kmod="net-pf-16-proto-5" scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=0
[  275.926349] init: Starting service 'ipv6proxy'...
[  275.927882] init: Starting service 'emu_hostapd'...
[  275.929091] init: Starting service 'zygote'...
[  275.930412] init: Starting service 'zygote_secondary'...
```

the logcat is here: [link](https://files.fm/u/p34rmm4s)

can anybody help?